Place reference grid over all ImageView
My app has a single ImageView in a LinearLayout. It currently places a photo in the ImageView, preserving the photo's AspectRatio by setting ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE. This results, correctly, in a display with background colour rectangles above or below (or left or right of) the photo.
Now, I'd like to place a reference grid over the entire ImageView area, that is, the photo plus the two background rectangles. The problem is determining the width and height of the total ImageArea to construct a grid bitmap that will occupy the ImageView. I can construct a 1000 x 1000 bitmap grid and place it in the ImageView with ScaleType.FIT_XY, but then I can't preserve the photo's AspectRatio in adding it to that square bitmap.
Ideally, I'd like to write a properly scaled grid over the existing photo.

I tried calculating the View size with DisplayMetrics information. Too many assorted system menubars to account for. In the end, did the best I could from DisplayMetrics information and then went to ScaleType.FIT_XY.  That left the images slightly mis-scaled, however.

would be helpfull if you've provided the layout that you got on trying your method...

The ImageView is the only item in the LinearLayout.

Create a custom Drawable that draws a grid and overlay it on the ImageView. This allows the grid to scale precisely with the ImageView.
Here’s how you can define and apply this overlay:
class GridOverlayDrawable(private val cellSize: Float, private val color: Int) : Drawable() {
    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = this@GridOverlayDrawable.color
        strokeWidth = 2f
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val width = bounds.width()
        val height = bounds.height()

        for (x in 0..width step cellSize.toInt()) {
            canvas.drawLine(x.toFloat(), 0f, x.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)
        }
        for (y in 0..height step cellSize.toInt()) {
            canvas.drawLine(0f, y.toFloat(), width.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), paint)
        }
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) { paint.alpha = alpha }
    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) { paint.colorFilter = colorFilter }
    override fun getOpacity() = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
}

Then, set this drawable as an overlay on the ImageView:
val gridOverlay = GridOverlayDrawable(cellSize = 20f, color = Color.LTGRAY)
imageView.overlay.add(gridOverlay)

If the ImageView dimensions don’t exactly match the image, adjust cellSize or use Matrix transformations to ensure the grid lines up with the scaled image.
